# Carving the second set of tablets in less than a day

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, aseres-hadibros

I don't know a lot about the tools and technologies that would have been available at the time, I wonder what Jewish opinion is on the carving. Is the command for Moses to carve the tablets by the next morning not a huge deal, or would such a thing be an enormous feat?